# Merge 'data-monitoring' and 'data-traffic'?

Tags: discussion, tags

[data-monitoring](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-monitoring) and [data-traffic](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-traffic) are extremely similar and have, approximately, the same popularity. Which one should be used? Should they be merged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have merged the latter into the former, and synonymized.  I think there may have been a reason we kept them separate originally, but actual usage didn't seem to reflect anything of the kind.  Thanks for bringing this up!